# Is there a way to add multiple filemasks in wx.lib.filebrowsebutton.FileBrowseButton?

Tags: python, wxpython, glob, filebrowse

I'm trying to make a `wx.lib.filebrowsebutton.FileBrowseButton` button match both txt and csv files, but it doesn't seem to support glob pattern as described, `*.{txt,csv}` ends up matching nothing on windows and it literally tries to look for files with extension of `{txt,csv}`.

So how do I make it work for both txt and csv files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation is not very clear. You should be using a semi-colon inside parenthesis, like so:  `"TXT and CSV files (*.txt; *.csv)|*.txt; *.csv"`

You can also add a second line like so: `"TXT and CSV files (*.txt; *.csv)|*.txt; *.csv|PNG files (*.png)|*.png"`

Comment: Yes! semi-colon it is!! Thanks a lot mate!!

Comment: By the way where do you find the related docs or maybe you just checked the source to figure out how it works?

Comment: wxPython docs are here: http://xoomer.virgilio.it/infinity77/wxPython/Widgets/wx.FileDialog.html. wx.FileDialog is well documented but some of the newer wxPython widgets like the filebrowsebutton are not as well documented. For those, I usually go to the source if I can.

Comment: Thanks again! Turns out I was looking at the wrong place all the time and trying to figure out a solution with several combinations...